# looking for django 1.2 to 1.3 migration detection script

Tags: django

migrating from one django version to the next, usually requires that you read the docs and check which functions / methods are deprecated. 
I.e, going from 1.2 to 1.3 one needs to replace the following [calls](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/topics/generic-views-migration/)

So what I usually do, is **grep** my source code for the functions in question. I was wondering whether someone has written a nice little python script or so, which goes through all code and gives you a digested list of all changes that are necessary.

Comment: The function-based generic views have been deprecated in version 1.3, but they will not be removed until 1.5. You don't *need* to replace them yet. A migration detection script might be useful, but I think it's important to read the release notes yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have full unit test coverage, you can just upgrade your Django and run your test suite. Deprecation notices will be given for any of your code which uses deprecated features.

If you don't have full unit test coverage then now is a good time to start writing them, so that your're prepared for when you upgrade from 1.3 to 1.4.